# RNRF - Actions.popTo failed: "called with an unknown routeName"

Tags: react-native, router, flux

Library Version

```
"react-native-router-flux": 4.1.0-beta.4  
"react": "16.8.3",  
"react-native": "^0.59.9"
```

I tried to call `Actions.popTo(sceneKey)` but it give `popTo called with an unknown routeName: pulsaScreen`. My desire screen that I want to pop to is `pulsaScreen`

When I log `Actions.prevState.routes` and give result:

```
[ { params: 
     { error: '',
       navigationBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FD6542', borderBottomWidth: 0 },
       leftButtonType: 'GO_TO_HOME_BUTTON',
       rightButtonType: 'CHAT_BUTTON_WITHOUT_LABEL',
       title: 'Beli Pulsa',
       navTransparent: false,
       titleStyle: 
        { .... },
       renderBackButton: null,
       renderLeftButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          ... },
       renderRightButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          ... },
       init: true,
       product_type: 1,
       type: 'reset',
       routeName: 'pulsaScreen' },
    routeName: 'pulsaScreen',
    key: 'id-1572259438287-3' },
  { params: 
     { error: '',
       navigationBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FD6542', borderBottomWidth: 0 },
       leftButtonType: 'BACK_BUTTON',
       rightButtonType: 'CHAT_BUTTON_WITHOUT_LABEL',
       title: 'Review',
       navTransparent: false,
       titleStyle: 
        { ... },
       renderBackButton: null,
       renderLeftButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          .... },
       renderRightButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          ... },
       init: true,
       routeName: 'reviewPulsaScreen' },
    routeName: 'reviewPulsaScreen',
    key: 'id-1572259438287-4' },
  { params: 
     { error: '',
       navigationBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FD6542', borderBottomWidth: 0 },
       title: 'Masukkan Pin',
       leftButtonType: 'BACK_BUTTON',
       rightButtonType: 'CHAT_BUTTON_WITHOUT_LABEL',
       navTransparent: false,
       titleStyle: 
        { .... },
       renderBackButton: null,
       renderLeftButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          ... },
       renderRightButton: 
        { '$$typeof': {},
          ... },
       init: true,
       routeName: 'pinInputScene' },
    routeName: 'pinInputScene',
   ...
    key: 'id-1572259438287-5'
```

`pulsaScreen` exist on route stack that I logged.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Now, I didn't know the answer. But, accidentally I use `Actions.jump()` and it worked as I expected.

Although, at the documentation, `Actions.jump()` only can be used on `Tab`